# Integral of a bessel function composed with a trigonometric function

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

Is there any standard way or approximated way to calculate an integral of the form

$$
\int_0^T J_n^2[a\cos(2\pi t/T)]dt
$$

where $J_n$ is the bessel function of first kind of order $n$?

Comment: G.N. Watson, A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions, ( 2nd.ed.), Cambridge University Press, 1966, page 32, gives Neumann's Series for $J^2_n(z)$ https://archive.org/details/ATreatiseOnTheTheoryOfBesselFunctions/page/n41

Comment: @JamesArathoon the series on page 32 looks different from the one you wrote in your answer. Is there an equivalence?

Comment: Have you considered changing the starting point of the sum to $n$? From Neumann's formula I immediately get $$J^2_n(x)=\sum _{k=n}^{\infty } \frac{  (-1)^{k-n} (2 k)!  }{2^{2 k} (k!)^2 (k+n)! (k-n)!}x^{2 k}$$

Comment: Alternatively you can adjust the integral at the bottom of my answer to include $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Using Maple I get a hypergeometric expression:

$$ {\frac {T{\mbox{$_2$F$_3$}(1/2+n,1/2+n;\,n+1,n+1,1+2\,n;\,-{a}^{2})}
\Gamma \left( 1/2+n \right) {a}^{2\,n}{4}^{-n}}{\sqrt {\pi} \left( n!
 \right) ^{3}}}
$$

EDIT: This is really telling you the series expansion in powers of $a$:

$$ \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k \Gamma(n+k+1/2)^2}{(k+n)!^2(k+2n)!k!} a^{2k+2n}$$

Comment: I would be much more interested in a more approximated solution, but more readable.

Comment: What $T$ stands for in this expression?

Comment: The same $T$ as you have in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I have mistaken the subscript and interpreted it as a function.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but I tried to plot the function (using $n$ as the independent variable) you wrote and the one I obtained using numerical integration and they look very different (your function looks roughly like a gaussian and the numerical result roughly like a sigmoid).

Comment: @JamesArathoon It is more than possible that I did something wrong. Would you mind post somewhere the images of both plots?

Comment: @AlessandroZunino: The values head to zero very quickly. To get a discrete formula you can substitute $$\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}=\frac{(2 n-1)\text{!!}}{2^n}$$ rather than implementing a Gamma function integral.

Answer (score 1):

This is another interesting conjectural result for any order of Bessel function of the first kind which can be compared with Robert Israel's Maple result.

$$\int_0^T J_n^2[a\cos(2\pi t/T)]\,dt=T \,\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{(-1)^{k+n} \binom{2 k}{k}^2  a^{2 k} } {(k!)^2\, 4^{2 k}   } \frac{\prod _{j=0}^{n-1} (k-j)}{\prod _{j=0}^{n-1} (j+k+1)}\right)$$

This result came from the inspection of series of $[J_n(x)]^2$
$$[J_n(x)]^2=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{(-1)^{k+n} \binom{2 k}{k}   }{ (k!)^2  \,2^{2 k}}\frac{\prod _{j=0}^{n-1} (k-j)}{\prod _{j=0}^{n-1} (j+k+1)} x^{2 k}\right)\tag{1}$$

together with the evaluation of the integral

$$\int_0^T \left(a \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  t}{T}\right)\right)^{2 k} \, dt=T\;\frac{   \Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\; \Gamma (k+1)}a^{2 k}=x^{2k}$$

So the conjectural step is equation (1).

Comment: How did you get this solution?

Comment: Hopefully this answers the question in the above comment and helps lead you to a proof.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference or a way to calculate the series of $J_n^2(x)$?

Comment: I used Mathematica to calculate the square of the series starting with $J_0$. I suppose you could write out a Cauchy product to calculate the square of the series by hand. I found a pattern for $J_n$ by investigating the first few orders in Mathematica and making use of OEIS. Therefore I didn't develop a proof for the squaring of a Bessel function of arbitrary order $n$.